# How to use the dynamic column name from the table in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the dynamic column names from the table using the 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' Following is the query.

```
Select  COLUMN_NAME into #TempTable 
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  where TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```

Result:

```
COLUMN_NAME
Person_ID
Person_Name
Person_Address
```

Wanting to Do:

```
Select * from MyTable where Person_ID = 1
```

What can be the ways to use the Person_ID from 1st query to the second query?

Comment: Why `Person_ID` specifically? Why not one of the other columns? What defines the column you choose (and the value you're comparing it to)? What actual problem are you solving?

Comment: I can't, from the vague detail we have, see any reason why this needs to be dynamic. If the column is specifically going to be `Person_ID`, then the column isn't dynamic, and the Table's name doesn't seem to be either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL to execute this via the `EXEC` command.

Build a `VARCHAR` string for your query based on the dynamic column names you are getting from your first query, then `EXEC` on the string you have created.

You have not provided enough information on exactly what columns you need in your `WHERE` clause, or how you determine which ones, but dynamic SQL seems to be what you need here.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to do something like this

```
select * from [table] where [col] =@param
```

then you can use query like below

```
   declare @query nvarchar(max)
    select 
      @query='select * from '+t.name + 
            ' where '+c.name + ' ='+
            case 
              when c.name ='Person_ID' then '1'
              when c.name ='Someother_ID' then '10'
              else c.name
            end

    from sys.tables t join sys.columns c 
    on c.object_id=t.object_id
    and t.name ='MyTable'
    exec(  @query)
```